# How can I repair a pinhole leak in a washing machine drain hose?

Tags: repair, pipe, washing-machine

I've just reconnected my washing machine and tested it, and there's a tiny hole in the out-flow pipe. The hole is in red circle in the images below ... in the fairly-rigid, ribbed plastic, rather than the rubber section with the black ziptie.

[image]

[image]

I'd guess the hole is the size of a large needle hole? Big enough to get a jet of water squirting out of it, but not so big that the pipe is obviously ruined.

Is there any particularly reliable way for me to mend this DIY? (I need to get it mended quickly, and don't really have the time to schedule a day that a plumber can come, and I can miss work :( )

- My first guess is to pour a little superglue over the hole?
- Another option might be sugru?
- Is there some way that I can trim back the pipe past the hole and then reconnect it?

It's not the pipe connected to the washing machine itself, I don't know where the pipe goes, but it's definitely not going to be easily accessible, wherever it is :(

Comment: Obviously I've already cleared up the water. There's also a lot of slack in the pipe on the washing machine side, and a little slack in the pipe on the wall side (i.e. the side with the hole)

Comment: The pipe _is_ ruined. The hole indicates damage or age and is a warning that bigger leaks are to come. Wrap it with some soft, sticky tape for now, but order a new one as soon as possible. They aren't expensive.

Comment: Can you reach the other end of the flexible hose? Is it buried?

Comment: @Harper I think it goes through the wall to the kitchen, behind the hob and dishwasher. Really avoid havingt move those if I can help it :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a short-term solution you can try [self-amalgamating tape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-amalgamating_tape), it is specifically made to be water-resistant and it forms a good seal. But with a leak like that I'd only recommend it as a stopgap until you can notify the landlord or hire a plumber. A hose like that should not be inside a wall so i'd recommend replacing it with rigid PVC when you can.

Answer (score 1):

Silicon sealant ("caulk") with any tape over it is good - see if your friends have an open tube. Move the ribbed pipe as little as possible since it looks hard to replace. If it was long and stable I would just chop it at the hole and re-attach to machine's hose.

Answer (score 0):

It may sound silly but a stainless steel screw should plug the hole, at least temporarily.

Try some 'stix all' or some similar rubbery adhesive, wait for it to dry (*in a smooth band*) and then hold in place with a jubilee clip.

Comment: Welcome to stack Exchange. When answering a question it best to be as detailed as possible, if you are recommending products or parts then please describe what they are. Not everyone knows what "stix all" or  a "Jubilee clip" is.  A photo helps or a web link. https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour